# A single word for the most important person in one's life

Tags: single-word-requests, literature, neologisms

The concept of a "[Lebensmensch](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=de&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLebensmensch)" plays a dominant role in Thomas Bernhard's works. At [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bernhard#Life) one reads that

> »Lebensmensch [is] a predominantly Austrian term [...] which refers to
>   the most important person in one's life«

This is a somehow typical usage of the word by Thomas Bernhard (from [Wittgenstein's Nephew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittgenstein%27s_Nephew), translated by DeepL):

> »But in truth, even without Paul, I would not have been alone on the
>   Baumgartnerhöhe in these days and weeks and months, for I had my
>   [*Lebensmensch*], the decisive one for me in Vienna after the death of my
>   grandfather, my [*Lebensmensch*], to whom I not only owe a great deal,
>   but, frankly, since the moment she appeared at my side over thirty
>   years ago, more or less everything. [...] The initiates know what
>   everything is hidden behind this word Lebensmensch, from and through
>   which I have drawn my strength and survival over thirty years, from
>   nothing else, that is the truth.«

For the sake of comparison, here the translation by Google:

> »But in truth, I would not have been alone at [Baumgartnerhöhe] these days and weeks and months without Paul, because I had my [*Lebensmensch*], the one who was decisive for me after the death of my grandfather in Vienna, my [*Lebensmensch*], who I not only much, but, frankly, since the moment she appeared by my side over thirty years ago, I owe more or less everything. […] The initiates know what is hidden behind this word "living person", from and from which I have obtained my strength and my survival over and over again, from nothing else, that is the truth.«

I wonder if there is such a beautiful one-word-term for the most important person in one's life (except for oneself) in the English language.

Comment: *My everything* or *my one and only* come to mind, but don't quite seem suited to dropping in here.

Comment: @MikeGraham: This sounds more like "my sweetheart" but from the quote above you will see, that this not exactly what I am after.

Comment: A single word for the most important person in my life... _Me_.

Comment: BAE. ^(Yes, I hate myself for suggesting that.)

Comment: _Heart_ and _soul_ are some strong terms of endearment. (_my heart_, _my soul_...). Another term is _number one_ and it can be used for anyone, not just for lovers/partners. (You are my _number one_ / _numero uno_).

Comment: No there isn’t. I suspect it is a relatively recent invention in German. When was it first used?

Comment: @David: Hard to tell. Wittgenstein's Nephew is from 1982. I didn't find any records  before Thomas Bernhard.

Comment: @KillingTime: So my question implicitly asked for a word for the most important person in one's life - except oneself;-) Now I made it explicit.

Comment: @KillingTime Technically "main squeeze" suffices because of the meaning of *main*, but that is arguably a less beautiful phrase. :) (I am trying to think of a word, FWIW.)

Comment: **Lifeline** is the word you're looking for.

Comment: @AndrewL64: I'm not quite sure. Could you please give a typical quote or usage?

Comment: Seems like while this woman might also have been his sweetheart the implication here is less about lovers and more about confidants, and complete trust. How about “My ***rock***”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the term you're describing is called a **term of endearment**, or a way to affectionately refer to a person you hold dear. There are many of them, from shortened names (Bess for Elizabeth) to animals (bunny) or sweet things (honey, sugar) to adjectives (beautiful, gorgeous).

The *most important person* is more specific. Your criterion suggests there is only one who is above all others. If you're trying to find a companion term (pun intended), you have a few options:

**Soulmate** or **soul mate**, as mentioned by another answer, suggests an ideal fit between two people who connect not merely physically but soul-deep. Oxford English Dictionary, "[soulmate, n.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/292748?redirectedFrom=soulmate#eid)":

> A person who shares a deep understanding or bond with another; esp. one ideally suited to another as a lover or spouse.

According to Merriam-Webster, Samuel Taylor Coleridge is said to have invented the word in an 1822 letter to a young lady, where he says:

> To be happy in Marriage Life, nay … in order not to be miserable, you must have a **Soul-mate** as well as a House or a Yoke-mate…

---

If you could go for a phrase, **the love of my life** is a common collocation for someone most dear to someone else. Even beyond the [Queen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUJkCXE4sAA) song, the phrase has had wide currency from the 19th century onward. For example, here is an excerpt from "Only A Flirtation." *Salem Observer*, vol. XL, no. 10, 8 Mar. 1862, p. [1](https://oed.com/view/Entry/292748?redirectedFrom=soulmate#eid), as found in [ReadEx's America's Historical Newspapers](https://infoweb.newsbank.com/apps/readex/?p=EANX) database:

> Day after day the love, the one **love of my life**, grew into my heart, absorbing me to the exclusion of all else.

Similar phrases extend back to Middle English, including **lef lif** (dear life) from the Middle English *[Sir Orfeo](https://d.lib.rochester.edu/teams/text/laskaya-and-salisbury-middle-english-breton-lays-sir-orfeo)*:

> O lef liif, what is te,
>
> That ever yete hast ben so stille
>
> And now gredest wonder schille?
>
> (O dear life, what is with you, who ever yet have been so calm, and now cry strangely shrill?)

---

Finally, English has a habit of borrowing terms of endearment from other languages. *Ma chérie* and *mon amie* both come from French; *inamorata* comes from Italian; there are many nonce uses based on users' language backgrounds. *Lebensmensch* is a coinage from the author Thomas Bernhard, and the book *[Thomas Bernhard](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Thomas_Bernhard/OXhmWKQY5cYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Lebensmensch&pg=PA59&printsec=frontcover)* by Gitta Honegger uses the word as-is when explaining it:

> While Frau Stavianicek remained Auntie to the world, in his books Bernhard coined the term *Lebensmensch* for her importance in his life. A simple enough compound of "life" and "person," it conveys so much more than its idiomatic English equivalent, "companion," used and elaborated as "life support" by the British translator of *Wittgenstein's Nephew*. (p. 59)

Why not just use **lebensmensch**, treating the sentiment behind it as effectively untranslatable? You can also translate it literally, accepting that it's a metaphor, as **life support** or (as just suggested in a comment by AndrewL64) **lifeline**?